# Image gallery won't stay in a grid

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

My goal: to produce a basic image gallery that can be printed to PDF from the browser as a 3col x 4row grid in a 8.5" x 11" portrait layout.  The image URL and a short description are fed from a django app, so I'll neither know how many images will be viewed nor the file names for them.

The code that follows is based on http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

It produces an image gallery whose result can be seen as a screenshot here:

[Image Gallery Screenshot](https://iesrailsolutions.net/static/imagelayout.png)

My question: is there a way to make the boxes stay in a fixed grid?  Some of the boxes are being pushed out of place, but I'm not sure why.  If there's a better solution, I hope you'll point me to it.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}

.text-box {
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h3>Section 14: Attachments</h3>
        {% for inspectionfeedback in inspection.inspectionfeedback_set.all %}
                {% if inspectionfeedback.feedback_image.path == "" %}

                {% else %}
                    <div class="floating-box">
                        <img src="{{ inspectionfeedback.feedback_image.url }}" style="width:140px;" alt=" " >
                        <div class="text-box">
                            {{ inspectionfeedback.feedback_inspection_item }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using inline-block, and the text is sometimes 3 lines or 2 or even four lines. The inline-block tries to level the text to "baseline" which in turn messes up your grid.

Possible solutions:

- use `display: block;`, and `float: left;` etc.
- use a `table` :(
- use `flex-box` (if you are ok with css)

Comment: I used a combination of your first two answers

This was the right combo to fix the grid problem.  
    display: block;     
    float: left;  

But, because I'm ultimately going to a PDF (printed page) I also used a table structure, which enabled me to eliminate page breaks in the middle of images and text.  

Thanks for your help!